# Get arguments and file name from specific path

Tags: c#

I'm trying to extract argument and file name from path like below:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\foo.exe foo://action/bar
```

I tried to use `Path.GetFileName` but since argument contains directory separators, it returns `bar` instead of `foo.exe`

Is there any way to get argument and file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LastIndexOf` to reverse-search the string for the backslash, then `Substring` to grab everything beyond that:

```
int i = path.LastIndexOf(@"\");
return (i > -1 && i < path.Length) ? path.Substring(i + 1) : string.Empty;
```

If you need to separate the filename and argument, use `IndexOf` to look for the space or `Split` the result on the space character.

Comment: Ideally, OS you plan to use this code would not support spaces in file path and both forward/backward slashes in file path... I don't know of one (this answer is not considering valid values for Windows file path... and Linux/Unix use "/" as path separators - so applicability is limited)

Comment: That's true, in Windows you can include spaces by putting an argument or pathname in quotes. If that happens the whole thing becomes significantly more complicated. I'd probably wind up using regex, but I haven't started drinking today yet, so there's no way I could cook up a working regex example.

(I assumed Windows because of the "exe" extension...)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the command line argument from the `string [] args` passed to the `Main` method.

Or you can use the static method `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I forgot to mention, that it is  path loaded from file